# Failed to build request: attribute named is defined

Tags: java, scala, testing, gatling

I am trying to pass my token to the required request but it does not save the variable "token".

The result is always "{token}" as you could collect the value you get in the .check (jsonPath ("$. User_id"). SaveAs ("userId"))

I have tried using ${token} but still not reused

Here you can see my code in case it helps you;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0kqp.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It either means that "getTokenRequest" failed, or that the users who perform "getNotificationClientId" don't first perform "getTokenRequest".